# Design an algorithm for finding the k-th largest element of an array in the presence of duplicates

Tags: algorithm

Design an algorithm for finding the k-th largest element of an array A in the presence of duplicates. The k-th largest element is defined to be A[k-1] after A has been sorted in a stable manner.

I can think of using quickselect algorithm but it isn't stable. An alternative is to use a binary heap and break ties in a stable manner (i.e. by time of insertion when scanning array from left to right), but this results in an algorithm with O(n * log k) time and O(k) space.

Is there a way to do this in O(n)? Please provide an implementation in java if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use O(n) extra space then the partition step of quickselect can easily be made stable in O(n) time: instead of swapping elements, just build up 4 separate lists (from-left-to-left, from-right-to-left, from-left-to-right, from-right-to-right) and then overwrite the original array with them in that order.

Comment: What do you mean by from-left-to-left, from-right-to-left, from-left-to-right, from-right-to-right? Please provide an example.

Comment: The partition step maintains two pointers i and j.  i points to the very start and advances forwards; j points to the very end, and advances backwards.  From-left is the list of elements visited by i and from-right is the list of elements visited by j (before the two pointers meet).  From-left-to-left is the subset of from-left that compares < pivot; from-left-to-right is the subset that compares >=.  Similarly for the other two.